# TestNG: print failed, passed, total tests executed in @aftersuite

Tags: testing, testng

Is there any way that I can print failed, passed, total tests executed in @aftersuite.

I know this can be done overriding ITestListener but is there any direct approach that I can get count in @aftersuite?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The below sample should show how this can be done.

```java
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Collection;

public class TestClassSample {
    @Test
    public void passingTestMethod() { }

    @Test
    public void failingTestMethod() {
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite(ITestContext context) {
        printSuiteResults(context.getSuite());
    }

    private void printSuiteResults(ISuite suite) {
        Collection<ISuiteResult> suiteResults = suite.getResults().values();
        for (ISuiteResult suiteResult : suiteResults) {
            printAllResults(suiteResult.getTestContext());
        }
    }

    private void printAllResults(ITestContext context) {
        System.err.println("Printing tests that passed.");
        printAllResults(context.getPassedTests().getAllResults());
        System.err.println("Printing tests that failed.");
        printAllResults(context.getFailedTests().getAllResults());
    }

    private void printAllResults(Collection<ITestResult> results) {
        for (ITestResult result : results) {
            printResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void printResult(ITestResult result) {
        System.err.println("Method Name: " + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "()");
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: null

    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:100)
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn46967666.TestClassSample.failingTestMethod(TestClassSample.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:669)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:877)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1201)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:776)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:634)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:426)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:421)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:386)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1318)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1243)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1161)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1129)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

Printing tests that passed.

Method Name: passingTestMethod()
Printing tests that failed.
Method Name: failingTestMethod()

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```